# Image undesired displacement using pstricks

Tags: pstricks

The following code:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,xcolor}
\usepackage{pst-all}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%\usepackage{pstricks}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
\begin{pspicture}
\psset{unit=1.5,linewidth=0.7mm,linecolor=red,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=yellow}
%,showpoints=true,dotsize=0.2}
\pspolygon(0,1.21)(2,1.21)(0.38,0)(1,2)(1.62,0)
\end{pspicture}
\vskip\baselineskip
The \rnode{A}{dog} has eaten \rnode{B}{his} bone.
\ncbar[angle=-90,nodesep=3pt,arm=.3]{->}{B}{A}
\end{document}
```

yields:

[image]

Why is the image displaced to the bottom of the page? Usually in TiKZ, which by the way I use more often, I just write the code and the image appears where it is supposed to be. How can I correct this?

Answer (score 4):

You need to specify the canvas size in advance. Canvas unit and graphics object unit should be set such that the graphics object lies inside the canvas.

```
\documentclass[a6paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
\bgroup
\psset{unit=1.5}
\begin{pspicture}(2,2)
\pspolygon[linewidth=0.7mm,linecolor=red,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=yellow]
    (0,1.21)(2,1.21)(0.38,0)(1,2)(1.62,0)
\end{pspicture}
\egroup
\vskip\baselineskip
The \rnode{A}{dog} has eaten \rnode{B}{his} bone.
\ncbar[angle=-90,nodesep=3pt,arm=.3]{->}{B}{A}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to get `pspicture` to adapt its size automatically to fit its contents (like `tikzpicture` does)?

Comment: @Jake: It is impossible. :-)

Comment: @GarbageCollector Any other advices about pstricks? Like what packages to load, technicalities,.....

Comment: @GarbageCollector Is there another way of doing away with the `\bgroup` and `\egroup`?

Comment: @azetina: There are many packages and to know which one to load we have to know them in advance. You can use `{` and `}` instead of `\bgroup` and `\egroup`. Grouping is needed to localize the effect of `\psset` settings.

Answer (score 1):

This is much in line with what *GarbageCollector* suggested.  I would just point out that the `pspicture` environment can take two coordinates to specify the lower left hand corner and upper right hand corner.  Also, I would put the `\psset{...}` outside the environment.  If you don't want it to take universal effect, place it all inside parentheses (see MWE below).

`pstricks` has some nice features such as `showgrid=true`.  Also by playing with the two coordinates you can get `pstricks` to overlay (or underlay) its image depending on where the image is placed.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,xcolor}
\usepackage{pst-all}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

{\psset{unit=1.5,linewidth=0.7mm,linecolor=red,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=yellow}
\begin{pspicture}(-3,2)(-3,2)
    \pspolygon(0,1.21)(2,1.21)(0.38,0)(1,2)(1.62,0)
\end{pspicture}}
\lipsum[1-2]

{\psset{unit=1.5,linewidth=0.7mm,linecolor=red,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=yellow}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=true](0,0)(2,2)
    \pspolygon(0,1.21)(2,1.21)(0.38,0)(1,2)(1.62,0)
\end{pspicture}}
\vskip\baselineskip
The \rnode{A}{dog} has eaten \rnode{B}{his} bone.
\ncbar[angle=-90,nodesep=3pt,arm=.3]{->}{B}{A}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Regarding what other packages you might find useful, that's hard to say without knowing what you want to accomplish.  I often use `pst-eucl` for drawing various geometry shapes (I teach a geometry course).  There are other more powerful means of drawing shapes, what I like about `pst-eucl` is that the commands are more in line with how you would do constructions.

I've recently being trying to teach myself `tikz`.  There is a lot that `tikz` can apparently do and in a more user friendly way than `pstricks`:  in fact, occasionally `pstricks` can be rather obscure.  For example, labeling node connectors can be done in `pstricks` but it seems to me that the method of doing this in `tikz` is cleaner and more transparent.

What **is** nice about `pstricks`---that I am particularly fond of---is the ability to embed post-script commands within it.